# Getting access to unmapped form fields in twig (Symfony 2.3)

Tags: php, forms, symfony, twig, symfony-2.3

I have form with hidden unmapped field:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        ...
        $builder
            ...
            ...
            ->add(
                'geolocationBreadcrumbs',
                'hidden',
                array(
                    'required' => false,
                    'mapped' => false
                )
            );
    }
```

I want to get access to value of that field in TWIG via {{ form.vars.value.field_name }}

```
<div>{{ form.vars.value.geolocationBreadcrumbs }}</div>
```

But I have an error: Method "geolocationBreadcrumbs" for object "Site\UserBundle\Entity\User" does not exist in "%path_to_twig_template%"

Why does Symfony 2.3 try to find method for unmapped field in Entity Class and how I can to get access to unmapped filed value direclty from twig?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can access value of this field calling:

```
{{ form.geolocationBreadcrumbs.vars.value }}
```

Calling `form.vars.value` you get access to User entity and that's why Symfony2 returns exception.

Comment: Great thanks. It's works. I will be very grateful, if you give to me link to symfony docs. It's interesting for me, because I don't find this way at http://symfony.com/doc/2.3/book/forms.html

Comment: I did not find this in symfony docs - i checked the source code of FormView class.